# A django form containing sub forms not showing validation errors for sub forms

Tags: django-forms, subform

In my page in django application it has multiple forms such that main form has sub forms .
When submitting I check for all the forms to be valid and if any of the form is invalid , it return the form_invalid function containing the main form .

But the problem is if any of the subform is invalid , it doesn't show any error and the fields are reset as well .

Here is the code when form is submit .

```
        if player_form.is_valid() and stats_form.is_valid() and contacts_form.is_valid() and extra_stats_form.is_valid():
        player = player_form.save(commit=False)
        stats_form = PlayerStatsForm(request.POST, instance=player.stats)
        stats = stats_form.save()

        contacts_form = PlayerContactsForm(request.POST, instance=player.contacts)
        contacts = contacts_form.save()

        extra_stats_form = PlayerExtraStatsForm(request.POST, instance=player.extra_stats)
        extra_stats = extra_stats_form.save()

        return redirect(self.get_success_url())
    else:

        return self.form_invalid(player_form)`
```

The get_context_data function which adds sub_forms into the main player form .

```
context.update({
        'object_title_plural': 'Players',
        'list_headings': self.list_headings,
        'form_panel_title': 'Add Player',
        'save_button_text': 'Add Player',
        'search_form': self.form_defaults(PlayerSearchForm()),
        'sub_forms': (self.form_defaults(self.get_form(PlayerStatsForm)),
                      self.form_defaults(self.get_form(PlayerContactsForm)),
                      self.form_defaults(self.get_form(PlayerExtraStatsForm)))
    })
```

Here is the template in which sub forms are rendered .

```
{% block display_subforms %}
                {% if sub_forms %}
                    {% include "dashboard/includes/sub_form.html" %}
                {% endif %}
            {% endblock %}
```

Comment: I know since the player form is only being returned which is the main form as well , only the validation error for that form would be displayed , but is there any way that i can show my sub form validation errors as well .